# What is Android trying to tell me with this pop up about selecting a SIM card?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sim-card, system-error, dual-sim

I have been getting this message for a short time.  Two changes are possibly the culprit:

1. I switched to cricket from tmobile on a tmobile phone. Shortly afterwards I started getting these.
2. I have a new ROM. OctOs M, which is based on Cyanogen.

I strongly suspect #1.  I've never seen this message before it started happening, and I don't know what its trying to say.

[image]

Phone is a T-Mobile Note 2. When I started with Cricket, it was still inadvertently locked, but I worked with T-Mobile to get it unlocked.

This phone physically cannot use more than 1 SIM.

If you didn't know, "Signal" is an app by OpenWhisperSystems.  Its a replacement sms and mms app. I have deregistered and reregistered with the app, and that did not affect this issue.

I did not do a factory reset when switching to the new service, so I wonder if something is up with Signal?

Comment: Is the ROM designed for dual SIM devices?

Comment: The ROM is designed for this particular phone, but they do have others they build at the same time.  Presumably it's an automated process though.

Comment: Potentially. Apologies I don't know the device very well, perhaps there's a dual SIM variant and the ROM has been designed to support both. If you haven't got an answer later on I'll have a dig about when I'm actually at a device I can search on properly. Out and about at the moment